# update php multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to update array based on pid and size s if product id and size both are matched whithin same array elements then it update the quantity by adding both the quantity and merge them in one index.Any help should be appreciated.
my code is:_

```
<?php

 $details = array ( "0"  => array ( "pid" => "402",
                                       "q" => "1",
                                       "s" => "0"
                                     ),
                   "1"  => array ( "pid" => "403",
                                       "q" => "2",
                                       "s" => "0"
                                     ),
                   "2"  => array ( "pid" => "402",
                                       "q" => "3",
                                       "s" => "0"
                                     ),
                   "3"  => array ( "pid" => "403",
                                       "q" => "1",
                                       "s" => "0"
                                     ),
                   "4"  => array ( "pid" => "405",
                                       "q" => "1",
                                       "s" => "0"
                                     ),
                );

?>
```

Output Should look like

output :

```
 0-pid 402 q 4 s 0
 1-pid 403 q 3 s 0
 4-pid 405 q 1 s 0
```

Comment: Please show some effort before asking for free code.

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach($details as $p)
{
  $output[$p["pid"]][$p["s"]]["q"]+=$p["q"];
}
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [402] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [q] => 4
                )

        )

    [403] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [q] => 3
                )

        )

    [405] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [q] => 1
                )

        )

)
```

You can then display the array in any format you like

Comment: OP isn't looking for that, he wants to merge the values `q` on the key `pid`. You do not have the correct `q` values here. it's poorly explained by the way.

Comment: And that is what it is. It does merge the values of q on each size on pid as required by the op :) `based on pid and size s if product id and size both are matched whithin same array elements then it update the quantity by adding both the quantity and merge them in one index`

Comment: There are 2 '402' pid, with 'q' values = 1 and = 3. Merging these should give a single '402' with 'q' value = 4, as we can see in OP' desired output. Your current output gives 'q' = 3 though. Your output is really not what OP wants.

Comment: Oops that was because of a missing + in the loop. I had to put `+=` and I put `=`. See the update now :)